# Alamofire with Swift 3.0 & Deployment Target 8.0

Tags: ios, ios8, swift3, alamofire

What is the way to integrate Alamofire with Swift 3.0 and also have to provide support for iOS 8 ? Is there any other option then Alamofire ?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest Cocoapods do like this

```
gem install cocoapods --pre
```

seems to solve the issue for my circumstance.

Comment: I think for that we have to use AlamofireDomain.

Comment: Alamofire with Swift 3.0 minimum deployment target is iOS 9, I don't know how this command (to upgrade cocoapods) can solve this...

Comment: `gem install cocoapods --pre` command allows you to install a pre-release version of cocoapods, there is no link to @jaimesh-patel's question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
    platform :ios, '10.0'
```

above this line only specification use this alamofire platform if u want all platform then remove this platform line  and second thing is deployment target select 8.0 so all  platform in use alamofire.

```
use_frameworks!

target '<Your Target Name>' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
end
```